# ruby2.2.1でrubocopが入りませんでした。checker ruby/rubocop: can't parse version string (abnormal termination?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Mac(Yosemite)でrubocopを使用したいと思ってます。

$ rubocop <ファイル名>

であれば、シンタックスチェックができます。

ただ、vimの中で、保存後のシンタックスチェックができないという問題です。

以下は作業履歴です。

=======================================================

以下の記事を参考にvimrcにrubocopを追加しました。 
http://qiita.com/yuku_t/items/0ac33cea18e10f14e185

※ruby 2.2.1の環境下でやってます。事情があって、rubyはこのバージョンで固定しております。

```
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive',
            \ 'active_filetypes': ['ruby'] }
let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers = ['rubocop']
```

しかし、以下の様なエラーが出ました。

```
syntastic: error: checker output:
warning: you are loading parser/ruby22 from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubyge
ms/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'.
warning: Ruby 2.2 is not released yet and parser support may be incomplete.
0.26.1
syntastic: error: checker ruby/rubocop: can't parse version string (abnormal termination?)
```

そこで、以下の記事を参考に、バージョンを落としました。 
http://qiita.com/ka2n/items/55a435c10a240ea5d434

parser: 2.2.0.pre.5 
Rubocop: 0.26.1

しかし、まだ、以下のようなエラーがでており、これ以上わかりませんでした。

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby22, which recognizes
warning: 2.2.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.2.1.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
0.35.1
```

調べていると、rubocopは最新版でないと、動作しないという記事を見かけましたが、
2.2.1では動作できないということでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

- [Rails - rubocopしたらparserの設定でwarningでた。 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/noripeex/items/2183154fb57bdb28f5e9)

Qiita の記事を参考に、エラーを吐かずに動作するparser gem(rubocop の依存gem)のバージョンを調べてみました。
Ruby 2.2.1 とRubocop が対応するparser gem のバージョンは 2.2.0.1 のようです

## 手順記録

- `bundle init` し、rubocop(バージョン指定なし), parser(バージョン指定あり)で記述
- 適当な`.rb`ファイルをvim で開き、保存操作。動作の確認。
- エラーが出れば、`gem uninstall rubocop parser ast;gem cleanup;`し、parser gem のバージョン指定を下げて、`bundle update`

これで、`bundle exec` をしなくても、エラー無く動作するgem の組み合わせが作れます。

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rubocop'
gem 'parser', '2.2.0.1'
```

Gemfile.lock に記録されているバージョンの関係は以下のようになりました:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ast (2.1.0)
    astrolabe (1.3.1)
      parser (~> 2.2)
    parser (2.2.0.1)
      ast (>= 1.1, < 3.0)
      slop (~> 3.4, >= 3.4.5)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    rainbow (2.0.0)
    rubocop (0.30.0)
      astrolabe (~> 1.3)
      parser (>= 2.2.0.1, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.4)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
    slop (3.6.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  parser (= 2.2.0.1)
  rubocop

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```